# Help with this problem please

Tags: graph-theory

I have to proof that in a graph $G$, if $n$ is the order and $m$ the size, if $G$ is connected then $$m \geq n -1.$$

I had thought about doing it by contradiction and then finding that if it is connected, the incidence matrix must have at least $n - 1$ edges, but I have the feeling that there is a more simple and understandable way of proving this, can you help me find it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you erase one edge, you can prove that you get at most two components.

This suggests induction by the number of edges...Don't forget to cover both the 1 and 2 components cases...

Comment: I see it is possible to use induction on the number of edges, then if we remove e we get a graph of G - 1 edges. 

The edge we remove might be a bridge. If it is we have 2 conn components each one of them having m >= n - 1 by I.H. But does this solve the initial case?

Comment: @Ruben The initial case means the case when you have $1$ edge... If your graph is connected, how many vertices do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can build up a connected graph by adding edges one at a time. The first edge connects two vertices. Each additional edge (which you can choose to have one end at an already connected vertex) adds at most one new vertex. Count.

Be careful to explain how you are using the connectedness, if you use this method.

Comment: Can we be sure that building the graph that way we use the minimum number of edges?

Comment: @Ruben No but we can get an inequality for the number of vertices after $r$ edges have been added - and you are trying to prove an inequality.

Comment: What would that inequality look like in terms of r and n?

Comment: @Ruben Since it is a homework question, I left you to work that out. After one edge is added, you have at most two vertices, after two edges are added you have at most three etc - it is very easy. You also have to show you can always add an edge in this way.